# How to integrate standalone Java EE 6 inside Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee, guice

I am facing issue with Maven 3.x where I am getting `Guice Provision error`.

With further debugging and investigation, I found the core issue that it is due to Java EE 6 not present inside my Eclipse IDE (Java EE 5 is there with one web server installed) and Guice library is looking for some Java Class which is available with Java EE 6.

Is it possible that I integrate the standalone JavaEE 6 inside Eclipse IDE without installing any webserver or updating the current one?

Comment: does it makes sense to include only JEE6 without a server? The easiest way would be to create a new JEE6 server and then you have the libraries included and you can also test your application.

Comment: It does make sense as Maven is using some library of J2EE 6, which is not present in J2EE 5, resulting in Guice Provision Error

Comment: Please stop calling J2EE (or even JEE). It was a decade ago renamed to Java EE. See also https://java.net/projects/javaee-spec/pages/JEE and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_EE_version_history

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a maven dependency for Java EE 6 (http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cjavax%7Cjavaee-api%7C6.0%7Cjar) to your project, and eclipse will gladly understand it.
However, your runtime will also need to be a Java EE 6 compliant container. Otherwise, you'd simply be looking for trouble. You may run into problems at runtime if you use a pre-Java EE 6 container (especially if you use newer features -- such as CDI).

Alternatively, if your library wants a specific feature (like, as I dare to guess, the CDI api), then you can add just the CDI jars to your classpath (check http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cjavax.inject%7Cjavax.inject%7C1%7Cjar)